# Dynamically register filters in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and I'm facing the following problem: dynamically register filters into my module.

I need to add every function of underscore.string. It could be boring:

```
// js/filters/underscore.string.js
angular.module('util')
    .filter('numberFormat', ['_s', function (_s) {
        return _s.numberFormat
    }])
    // another filter, another filter, another filter, ...
    ;
```

(`_s` is underscore.string service)

I *could* do this:

```
// js/filters/underscore.string.js
var util = angular.module('util');
angular.forEach(window.s, function (v, k) {
    if (angular.isFunction(v)) {
        util.filter(k, function (_s) {
            return _s[k];
        });
    }
});
```

But I'm using the global `s` and not the service `_s`. It feels wrong.

Do you think this is a bad idea? Consider I'm managing dependencies using bower with `x.y.*` semver, so I should base "safe" in terms of changes.

**EDIT**: another working solution, but again it feels bad; a service provider registering also its filters and using the global `window`:

```
angular.module('util')
    .provider('_s', ['$filterProvider', function ($filterProvider) {
        var s = window.s;
        angular.forEach(s, function (val, key) {
            if (angular.isFunction(val)) {
                $filterProvider.register(key, function () {
                    return s[key];
                });
            }
        });

        this.$get = ['$window', function ($window) {
            return $window.s;
        }]
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.config(function($filterProvider) {
    var fns = {};
    Object.keys(_.str).reduce(function(obj, key) {
        fns[key] = function() {
            return _.str[key];
        };
    }, {});
    $filterProvider.register(fns);
})
app.run(function($filter) {
    console.log($filter('slugify')('hello world'))
})
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LtrquC9kml7dJClDoXFk?p=preview)

Comment: Ok, but correct me if I'm wrong: you are dealing with _.str global, like in my example?

Comment: Sure, but why is that wrong? it's going to be global unless you take the external script and wrap it in a service (and even then it's going to be global because angular is global).